# Laravel CSV file reading Angular as front

Tags: php, laravel, csv

Good day everyone!

I have a CSV file, inside this:

1.453453,4.578413,0.314132,0.764312,0.123422
2.453453,3.578413,0.764312,0.314132,0.123422
3.453453,2.578413,0.123422,0.764312,0.314132
4.453453,1.578413,0.314132,0.123422,0.764312

To read this in postman this is my code:

```
    $keys = ['PGA', 'PGV', 'X-Axis', 'Y-Axis', 'Z-Axis'];
    $json = [];
    $path = Storage::path('upload/test.txt');
    $file = fopen($path, 'r');
    while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== false) {
         $json[] = array_combine($keys, $line);
    }
    fclose($file);
    return json_encode($json);
```

The output is :

```
[
    {
        "PGA": "1.453453",
        "PGV": "4.578413",
        "X-Axis": "0.314132",
        "Y-Axis": "0.764312",
        "Z-Axis": "0.123422"
    },
    {
        "PGA": "2.453453",
        "PGV": "3.578413",
        "X-Axis": "0.764312",
        "Y-Axis": "0.314132",
        "Z-Axis": "0.123422"
    },
    {
        "PGA": "3.453453",
        "PGV": "2.578413",
        "X-Axis": "0.123422",
        "Y-Axis": "0.764312",
        "Z-Axis": "0.314132"
    },
    {
        "PGA": "4.453453",
        "PGV": "1.578413",
        "X-Axis": "0.314132",
        "Y-Axis": "0.123422",
        "Z-Axis": "0.764312"
    }
]
```

but I need to add 'data:' before the data and be inside another `{}`:
like this:

```
{    
  "data":  [
        {
            "PGA": "1.453453",
            "PGV": "4.578413",
            "X-Axis": "0.314132",
            "Y-Axis": "0.764312",
            "Z-Axis": "0.123422"
        },
        {
            "PGA": "2.453453",
            "PGV": "3.578413",
            "X-Axis": "0.764312",
            "Y-Axis": "0.314132",
            "Z-Axis": "0.123422"
        },
        {
            "PGA": "3.453453",
            "PGV": "2.578413",
            "X-Axis": "0.123422",
            "Y-Axis": "0.764312",
            "Z-Axis": "0.314132"
        },
        {
            "PGA": "4.453453",
            "PGV": "1.578413",
            "X-Axis": "0.314132",
            "Y-Axis": "0.123422",
            "Z-Axis": "0.764312"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using angular as my front end and i need this to be shown. so i need to add the said above. thanks for every help you give! I have to put ' data: ' to call it inside the web page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $keys = ['PGA', 'PGV', 'X-Axis', 'Y-Axis', 'Z-Axis'];
    $json = [];
    $path = Storage::path('upload/test.txt');

    $file = fopen($path, 'r');
    while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== false) {
        $json[] = array_combine($keys, $line);
    }
    fclose($file);

    $modified = ["data" => $json];

    return json_encode($modified);
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation or comments to the code rather than just a block of code.